# Mongoose expire inside object array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a notifications object array inside my User schema. I want to make each notification expire after say an x amount of time. Is that possible? Other answers I've followed have given me errors.

I've tried adding `createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 7200}`
 to both my User schema and notification push array. The "type: Date" seems to be what's breaking it.

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  uuid: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  keep: {
    type: String
  },
  notifications: [{notifcationType: String, date: String, user: String, _id: false, createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 7200} }],
  followers: [{user: String, date: String, _id: false}],
  following: [{user: String, date: String, _id: false}]
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

//my function to push notifications that a user followed. Works without the createdAt object

module.exports.addFollowNotify = (id, user, options, callback) => {
  const query = {username: user.following}
    let update = {
    $push: {notifications: {user: user.username, date: user.date, notifcationType: "Follow", createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 7200} }}
    };
    User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, callback);
};
```

Comment: Please tell clear your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to create new collection of 'notifications' and create new notification with reference of userid. This way you can read user's notification and notification will delete as per expire time.